# How is String arr = new String[] not possible in Java

Tags: java, reference

i have trouble understand reference types in Java. So in C++ if we wanna allocate some 1D array dynamicly or single object all we do is:

```java
int *a = new int();
int *a = new int[];
```

But in Java pointers are not avaliable to programers, references are introduced as some type of pointers but without possibilty of arithemtic operation on the value they hold(point?).

As far as i know every non-primitive data type in Java is of type reference :

```java
String obj; //reference
obj = new String();
```

And if wanna allocate it something we gotta allocate it on heap, and the obj will hold the adress of that object on heap. So in C++ it would be like :

```java
String *obj = new String();

But for the array we gotta do :

String[] obj = new String[];
```

And I dont understand why exactly? If obj is already of  reference type(simple *ptr)  why cant we just do :

String obj = new String[];

How does this exactly work in Java?
Is `String[]` obj actualy **ptr in C++ or am i missing something?

Comment: No. A Java array is never of it's component type (except for `Object`). `Object` is the root of the type hierarchy. `Object obj = new String[] {"Hello", "World"};` is legal and fine. Because an array is an `Object`. But it's never a `String`. Note that `Object obj = new int[] {1,2};` is also fine. Because an `int[]` is an `Object`. Not an `int`. Java is not descended from C and it has strong typing.

Comment: Java arrays are much more than pointers to the first elements in them.  They have an entire object header, a length field, and everything.

Comment: Java references are not C/C++ pointers. A Java reference is just something that may leads to an object. The type of the reference must corresponds to the type of the object. You better should not think of references as pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you can't write

```
String obj = new String[];
```

is that the left-hand side and right-hand side have different types.  That's all there is to it.  An array of Strings is not a String.  A reference to an array of Strings is not a reference to a String.

Maybe more fundamentally, Java is not C++.